# Почему не работает сортировка

Tags: c#, linq

```
 var uz = (from line in readText
     let a = line.Split(',')
     where a.Length >= 5 && Regex.IsMatch(a[4], @"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}")
     let Num = a[1]
     let timeAttr = a[4].Split(':')
     let timeUsage = TimeSpan.FromHours(int.Parse(timeAttr[0])) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(int.Parse(timeAttr[1])) + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(int.Parse(timeAttr[2]))
     select new { Num, timeUsage } into Uzel
     group Uzel by Uzel.Num into g
     select new { Num = g.Key, TotalTime = new TimeSpan(g.Sum(arg => arg.timeUsage.Ticks)), AverageTime = new TimeSpan((long)g.Average(arg => arg.timeUsage.Ticks))}

 );
 var sort = from lin in uz
   orderby lin.Num
   select lin;
 foreach (var z in uz)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("На {0} узле время отклонения равно {1} среднее время {2:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", z.Num, z.TotalTime, z.AverageTime);
     W.WriteLine("На {0} узле время отклонения равно {1} среднее время отклонения на узле {2:hh\\:mm\\:ss} ", z.Num, z.TotalTime, z.AverageTime);
 }
```

Comment: Вообще не реагирует(

Answer (score 1):

Потому что LINQ-шный `orderby` создаёт **новую** последовательность, а не сортирует старую.

Пробуйте `foreach (var z in sort)`

Comment: Спасибо получилось